# invalid materialized view when renaming a table used in the its query. ORA-00942 and ORA-06512, oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am trying to replace a table used by a materialized view and replace it with a synonym. The mview becomes invalid and needs to be dropped and recreated to make it work. Is there any other way to fix the mview without dropping it?

```sql
-- create test for issue with materialized views
create table tab_20211101 (first_name varchar2(100) primary key );
insert into tab_20211101 (first_name) values ('abc');
commit;
create materialized view log on tab_20211101 with rowid, primary key including new values;
create materialized view tab_20211101_mv refresh fast on commit as select * from tab_20211101;
select * from tab_20211101_mv;

-- now rename the table
drop materialized view log on tab_20211101;
alter table tab_20211101 rename to tab_20211101_new_name;
create materialized view log on tab_20211101_new_name with rowid, primary key including new values;

-- materialized view is now invalid, makes sense
select * from USER_OBJECTS a where a.OBJECT_NAME like 'TAB_20211101%' and STATUS = 'INVALID';
create synonym tab_20211101 for tab_20211101_new_name;

-- mv query works
select * from tab_20211101
-- materialized view still invalid, hmmm
select * from USER_OBJECTS a where a.OBJECT_NAME like 'TAB_20211101%' and STATUS = 'INVALID';

/*
 cannot refresh with ugly error
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3020
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2432
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 88
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 253
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2413
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2976
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3263
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3295
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 16
 */
begin
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TAB_20211101_MV');
end;

drop materialized view tab_20211101_mv;
create materialized view tab_20211101_mv refresh fast on commit as select * from tab_20211101;
-- mview is now valid
select * from USER_OBJECTS a where a.OBJECT_NAME like 'TAB_20211101%' and STATUS = 'INVALID';
```

edit 2021.11.01 13:02: a similar strategy seems to work for synonyms

```sql
create table tab_20211101 (a int primary key);
create synonym tab_20211101_syn for tab_20211101;
select * from tab_20211101_syn; -- OK
alter table tab_20211101 rename to tab_20211101_new;
select * from tab_20211101_syn; -- ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid
create synonym tab_20211101 for tab_20211101_new;
select * from tab_20211101_syn; -- OK
```

Comment: No way around a recreate, but consider using PREBUILT TABLE on both the original create and the subsequent one, which means the recreation will be instantaneous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because object id has changed. In your case the synonym will not work unless you recreate the MVIEW. Even `COMPILE` the Materialized view will change the status to `VALID` but transactions will not work.

***This demo only covers a scenario where you have a table, a materialized view log over it, and a materialized view with fast refresh***

Demo ( Oracle 19c )

```
SQL> create table test.t2 ( c1 number, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view log on test.t2 ;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view test.mv_t2 refresh fast on commit as select * from test.t2 ;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * from test.mv_t2 ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          3
```

Now, let's drop the `MLog`, rename the `table` and create the `synonym`

```
SQL> drop materialized view log on test.t2 ;

Materialized view log dropped.

SQL> alter table test.t2 rename to t2_old ;

Table altered.

SQL> create or replace synonym test.t2 for test.t2_old ;

Synonym created.
```

After recreating the log, the materialized view is invalid

```
SQL> create materialized view log on t2_old ;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> select object_name , status from user_objects where object_name = 'MV_T2' ;

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STATUS
-------
MV_T2
VALID

MV_T2
INVALID
```

After compiling

```
SQL> alter materialized view test.mv_t2 compile ;

Materialized view altered.

SQL> select object_name , status from user_objects where object_name = 'MV_T2' ;

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STATUS
-------
MV_T2
VALID
```

But, if I want to insert

```
SQL>  insert into test.t2 values ( 4 ,4 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  commit ;
 commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Why ?

**Materialized view and synonym dependencies are based on the object id in the data dictionary, not the object name, so if you rebuild a source table, view, or synonym, you have no choice to rebuild the materialized view as well even if everything has the same names.**

Comment: @user103716 , you are very welcome.

Comment: actually, what you say doesn't seem to hold for synonym dependencies. They handle this renaming transparently. ```create table tab_20211101 (a int primary key);
create synonym tab_20211101_syn for tab_20211101;
select * from tab_20211101_syn; -- OK
alter table tab_20211101 rename to tab_20211101_new;
select * from tab_20211101_syn; -- ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid
create synonym tab_20211101 for tab_20211101_new;
select * from tab_20211101_syn; -- OK```

Comment: it does, as long as you are dropping the materialized view log. My demo only covers this scenario: you have a table, a mlog and materialized view. before renaming the table, you need to drop the mlog. when you recreate the mlog, the mview will  compile, but the insert will not work

Comment: it will work if you don't have a materialized view log ( so refresh on demand ). I test that approach and it seems to work, as long as the materialized view refresh does not  need any log